# Run time error 9: subscript out of range (error while pasting)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm relatively new to VBA. I'm trying out the following VBA code but its throwing an error: 'Runtime error 09: subscript out of range'. This error occurs when i'm trying the paste operation in Graph 1 section of the code..

can someone help with figuring out as to where i'm going wrong. I have declared the presentation/slide etc. still i'm facing this problem..

```
Sub UK()

Dim oPPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
 Dim oPPTFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
 Dim oPPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
 Dim oPPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
 Dim SlideNum As Integer
 Dim mycells As Range
 Set oPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
 srcdir = "D:\WBR\Week 2"
 srcfile = srcdir & "\" & Dir(srcdir + "\*.pptx")
 Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.Presentations.Open(srcfile)
 Set oPPTSlide = oPPTFile.Slides(2)


' for graph 1
 Set oPPTShape = oPPTFile.Slides(2).Shapes("Picture 3") 
 oPPTShape.Delete

 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Charts").Activate
 Sheets("New Charts").Shapes.Range(Array("Group 21")).Select
 Selection.CopyPicture

 oPPTApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Select 
 Set Picture = oPPTSlide.Shapes.Paste
 Picture.Name = "Picture 3" 

With oPPTApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("Picture 3") 
  .Top = Application.InchesToPoints(3)
  .Left = Application.InchesToPoints(0.22)
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to:

- Open a saved presentation
- Delete "Picture 3" from Slide 2
- Copy Chart/Range from your excel sheet
- Paste it in Slide 2
- Name it as "Picture 3"
- Set it's position on the slide

Well the below code does exactly that:

```
'Make Sure to load the PowerPoint Object Library
'Tools ---> References ---> Microsoft PowerPoint xx.x Object Library

    Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim objChart As Chart

    Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application

    'presentation path here
    srcdir = "C:\"
    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(srcdir & "Presentation" & ".pptx")

    Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides(2)

    For j = 1 To pptSlide.Shapes.Count
        With pptSlide.Shapes(j)
    If .Name = "Picture 3" Then
    .Delete
    End If
        End With
    Next j

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    'Change "Chart 1" to the name of your chart if you are copying a chart
    Worksheets("New Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    Set objChart = Worksheets("New Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
    objChart.CopyPicture

    'If you are copying a range of cells then use
    Worksheets("New Charts").Range("A1:A10").Copy

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Set MyPic = pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)

    With MyPic
    .Name = "Picture 3"
    End With

    With pptSlide.Shapes("Picture 3")
    .Top = Application.InchesToPoints(3)
    .Left = Application.InchesToPoints(0.22)
    End With

    'use this line to set focus to slide 2 if you want to
    pptPres.Slides(2).Select

    pptPres.Save 'use this line to save if you want to

    Set pptSlide = Nothing
    Set pptPres = Nothing
    Set pptApp = Nothing
```